# Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

Here am trying to loop through an observable using the async pipe and its showing that the object is null.

```
 <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let i of (ingredients | async).ingredient;let val=index">
    <a class="list-group-item" style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="editIngredients(val)">{{i.name}} {{i.number}}</a>
    <br>
</ul>

export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients:Observable<{ingredient:ingredients[]}>
  constructor(private scr:ShoppingService,private testingService:TestingServices,
    private store:Store<{ModuleActivateReducer:{ingredient:ingredients[]}}>) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ingredients=this.store.select('ModuleActivateReducer')
    console.log(this.ingredients,"store data ing")
  }
  editIngredients(id:number){
    this.scr.ingdredientsById.next(id)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `ingredients | async` will evaluate to `null` until the observable emits a value.  So attempting to access a property like `(ingredients | async).ingredient` will initially give you an error.

You can avoid this by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?`):

> If the object is undefined or null, it returns undefined instead of throwing an error

```html
<ul *ngFor="let i of (ingredients | async)?.ingredient">
  ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if `https://stackoverflow.com/users/1858357/bizzybob` code doesnot work,
try this also, make `ingredients` undefined.
**ingredients**:**Observable<**{ingredient:ingredients[]}**>** **| undefined**;